# Local function variable change not effecting variable in global scope. Why not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm creating a simple weather application in js/jquery. One component of the simpleweather function is that it should globally effect the **var** fahrenheit, yet when I call it later in the if/else statement it logs in the **var** fahrenheit logs as 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
var fahrenheit = 0;
var celsius = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.simpleWeather({

    location: 'newyork, NY',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
    //renames weather.temp as fahrenheit
     fahrenheit = weather.temp;
    console.log(fahrenheit);
     //puts that value into .fahrenheit div
      $(".fahrenheit").html(fahrenheit);
      //converts to celsius then puts in .celsius div
       celsius = fahrenheit - 32;
    var celsius = celsius * 5;
    var celsius = celsius / 9;
    var celsius = parseInt(celsius);
    $(".celsius").html(celsius);
    },
  });
});

if (fahrenheit > 55) {
    $(".scarf").html('<img src="img/scarf.svg"></img>');

} else {

    $(".scarf").html("");
};
```

Comment: Why are you redeclaring the variable `celsius` in the onready eventhandler?

Comment: Your success handler is nested inside of two asynchronous operations `$(document).ready()` and `$.simpleWeather()`.  That means those operations will complete some time LATER.  Meanwhile, your `if (fahrenheit > 55)` code will have run BEFORE those async operations have completed.  Put all code that needs to results INSIDE the `success` handler function itself.

Comment: @cmate I was basing my syntax off of a variable exercise. My understanding was that this was the correct syntax for changing a variable using the same variable.

Comment: @jfriend00. Thank you. This was the key. I was console logging "test" throughout the document and this function was running later than the others, but I could not figure out why. I removed the `$(document).ready()` hander but had not realized `$.simpleWeather` would run later as well. Thanks!

Comment: @sjos - if something takes a callback that is called when the operation is complete, then it is probably an async operation that is called sometime later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the below code inside the `success` callback. (Ajax works **asynchronous**.)

```
if (fahrenheit > 55) {
    $(".scarf").html('<img src="img/scarf.svg"></img>');
} else {
    $(".scarf").html("");
};
```

Comment: thanks @xdazz. I didn't realize the functions were running asynchronously. This solution worked for me!